# AngularJS REST service doesn't work when loading page content using Ajax

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, rest

I have a REST service that fetch data from back end and show the notifications to user when click notification button.Initially notification div is hide and when button click it will show with REST data.As a draw back i have figured out REST call takes sometime to load and it will cause my main page loading slow. Because even without click notification button data will be loaded.As a solution i integrated ajax to load the notification div content.In ajax call i load html page into notification div using ajax.

*ajax code snippet when notification button click*

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("label").click(function() {

            $.ajax({
                url: "notify/notification.html",
                success: function(result) {
                    $(".ajax-notifications").html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In notification.html i call the REST service.But the problem is that page successfully load but REST call doesn't execute.Even doesn't show any errors in console.I am newbie to Angularjs appreciate any help or any ideas to do this in better way.

*Main Page*

```
<div class="ajax-dropdown" style="left: 128px;">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-default">
<input type="radio" name="activity" id="javascript:void(0)">
                Notifications (0) </label>

  </div>

    <!-- notification & tasks content -->
    <div class="ajax-notifications custom-scroll">
    <div class="alert alert-transparent">
        No Notification or Tasks available at this time.
    </div>
    </div>
        </span>
        </div>
```

*notification html*

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="postExample">

        <head>
            <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-resource.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/usersController.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/userRepoService.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body ng-controller="UsersController">
             <h1>Notifications</h1>

            <select id="UserSelector" style="width: 100%;">
                <option ng-repeat="user in users" value="{{user.displayName}}">{{user.displayName}}</option>
            </select>
        </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: You are using jQuery to load the Ajax. Look at $http or $resource services. Angular has better promises and fully integrated with angular

Comment: @ Shaun the same code snippet working fine when i insert into main page.so my REST service works fine but the problem is when i insert code snippet into another page my REST service doesn't execute.

Comment: Appreciate that @gihan. Was more a general comment you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Is your button click event triggered at any point of time ? `$("notify").click()` . Are you binding click event to appropriate component ?

Comment: May be this might help you , if you need to use jQuery instead of $http/$resource - http://jonathancreamer.com/using-jquery-ajax-in-an-angular-app/ As @shaun suggested its not the best way what you doing. Please go through angular doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http to get an idea

Comment: Also, what's the $("notify").click? There is no notify element in your code.

Comment: I edited the question please have a look.Note:I use $http to call the REST service in angular.My requirement is to just load the notification page into main page and notification page itself called the REST service.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try $http function of angular instead of use jQuery ?

On Controller :

```
$scope.clickcall = function () {
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/notify/notification.html'
   }).then(function successCallback(response) {
       //Do what ever you want with returned data//
       console.log(response);
   });
};
```

and use this $scope function for ng-click event.

Answer (score 0):

I think that angularJS don't know the `$.ajax()` request and it is not in angular context so if you want to run it with angularJS add your code inside `$scope.$apply(function(){ ... })` like this:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: "notify/notification.html",
            success: function(result) {
                $(".ajax-notifications").html(result);
            }
        });
});
```